# Show that the map $\varphi : \chi \to \psi_{\chi}$ is continuous.

Tags: continuity, lp-spaces, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, characters

> Let $\chi$ be a character of $\mathbb Z$ i.e. $\chi : \mathbb Z \longrightarrow S^1$ is a group homomorphism. Define $\psi_{\chi} : \ell^1 (\mathbb Z) \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ by $\psi_{\chi} ((a_n)_{n \geq 1}) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_n \chi (n).$ Then it is easy to show that $\psi_{\chi}$ is a multiplicative linear functional on $\ell^1(\mathbb Z),$ when considering $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ as a Banach algebra with respect to the convolution product. Let $\widehat {\mathbb Z}$ be the set of all characters of $\mathbb Z.$ Endow $\widehat {\mathbb Z}$ with the compact open topology. Now define a map $\varphi : \widehat {\mathbb Z} \longrightarrow (\ell^1(\mathbb Z))^*$ by $\chi \mapsto \psi_{\chi}.$ **Show that $\varphi$ is continuous.**

This problem has been left as an exercise in the lecture note I am following. I have tried to show that but I couldn't quite able to do it. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The arrow $\text{“}{\mapsto}\text{”}$ should be used for things like the statement that the function $x\mapsto(x+2y)^2$ differs from the function $y\mapsto(x+2y)^2.$ I edited the subject line of this question accordingly.

Comment: Which topology do you endow $\mathbb Z$ with? If it's the discrete topology, I don't think the statement is correct since $\mathbb Z$ is not compact in that topology.

Comment: @amsmath $\mathbb Z$ is endowed with the discrete topology.

Comment: @amsmath what will happen if we endow weak or weak* topology on $(\ell^1(\mathbb Z))^*$ instead of norm topology? For weak* topology we only need to show pointwise convergence of $\psi_{\chi_n}$ to $\psi_{\chi}$ if $\chi_n \to \chi$ with respect to the compact open topology. Will it necessarily hold?

Comment: Note that $(\ell^1(\mathbb Z))^* = \ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)$. And actually, I don't know anything about the weak topology on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @RabinKumarChakraborty I think the typesetting in your original question was correct. If you think so, too, you can revert the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Z$ is cyclic, group homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z$ to $S^1$ are in bijective correspondence with elements of $S^1$ via $\chi\mapsto \chi(1)$. The inverse map is given by $z\mapsto (n\mapsto z^n)$, and it is not hard to see that it is continuous. Since $S^1$ is compact, this means that it is a homeomorphism. So we may just as well consider $\phi\colon S^1\to \ell^1(\mathbb Z)^\ast,\,z\mapsto (a\mapsto\sum_n a_n z^n)$ instead of the map from the question.

This map is not continuous if we endow $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)^\ast$ with the norm topology: If $z_m=e^{\pi i/m}$ with $m\in\mathbb Z$, then $z_m^m=-1$ and therefore
$$
\|\phi(z_m)-\phi(1)\|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb Z}|z_m^n-1|=2.
$$
But of course $z_m\to 1$.

The map $\phi$ is continuous if we endow $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)^\ast$ with the weak$^\ast$ topology: If $z_k\to z$ in $S^1$ and $(a_n)\in \ell^1(\mathbb Z)$, then $|a_n z_k^n|\leq |a_n|$ and thus
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_nz_k^n\to\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n z^n
$$
by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: That means we have a induced map from $C \left (\widehat {\ell^1 (\mathbb Z)} \right )$ onto $C(\mathbb S^1)$ if $\widehat {\ell^1 (\mathbb Z)}$ is endowed with the Gelfand topology, where $\widehat {\ell^1 (\mathbb Z)}$ is the space of all non-zero multiplicative linear functionals on $\ell^1 (\mathbb Z).$

Comment: In fact the induced map is a $\mathbb C$-algebra isomorphism.

Comment: With the help of these results I just proved **Wiener's $\frac {1} {f}$ Theorem** which gives absolutely convergent Fourier series of the reciprocal of a non-vanishing continuous function defined on the unit circle which also has absolutely convergent Fourier series. It's a great result. Thanks @MaoWao for your help.